# Sentinel Package: Getting all logged in Users

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentinel

I'm using Sentinel in Laravel for user management. I logged in 2 users and I try to get a list of all logged in users but this only returns the very last user to log in. 
The code below is one of my attempts. I know im doing it wrong pls help.

```
public function getLoggedInUsers(Request $request,User $user) 
{
    $loggedinUser ="";

    foreach($user as $loggedinUser){
        return Sentinel::getUser($loggedinUser);
    }
 }
```

It returns only the last logged in User instead of a list of all logged in users

Answer (score 0):

The **return** key will exit the function getLoggedInUsers() the first time it is hit. This means your foreach loop is only executing one time and immediately returning the first user. Additionally, your $user variable is a single user, meaning there is nothing to loop over, it will only execute one time regardless.
I could not find in the documentation if Sentinel has a function for getting all active users.

I'm not sure if Sentinel supports it, but if the User sessions can be saved to the database instead of the filesystem, then you should be able to check to the sessions table for active users. In basic Laravel authentication, you can change where the user sessions are stored. Sentinel might have something similar or might use config/session.php as well. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session)
[image: User Sessions]

Comment: thanks alot for your reply, i'll look into it  more as I'll be using Sentinel a whole lot